Electron, node.js, next.js - bluetooth serial get device name - serial web api
I have a small electron + next.js + typescript + ES application running and I'd like it to list all connected bluetooth devices on my pc.
Currently, I'm able to list those but only their information is shown without the device name like "myIphone" or "earbuds brandname pro+". What is a good way to do so?
I've tried multiple other bluetooth node modules but they are almost all deprecated and will not work with the latest versions of the tools electron, next.js, typescript and ES.
Setup:

Node.js 18.16.1,
Chromium 116.0.5845.228,
Electron 26.6.10.


npm -v: 10.5.0




node -v: 20.12.2 (why is this different from node.js? )



index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
    Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
    and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.

    <button id="clickme">Test Serial</button>
    
    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

main.js:
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-features', 'ElectronSerialChooser')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      enableBlinkFeatures: 'Serial'
    }
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.session.on('select-serial-port', (event, portList, webContents, callback) => {
    console.log('SELECT-SERIAL-PORT FIRED WITH', portList);
    
    //Display some type of dialog so that the user can pick a port
    /*dialog.showMessageBoxSync({
      ....
      ...
      ...
    });*/
    event.preventDefault();
    
    let selectedPort = portList.find((device) => {      
      // Automatically pick a specific device instead of prompting user
      //return device.vendorId == 0x2341 && device.productId == 0x0043;

      // Automatically return the first device
      return true;
    });
    if (!selectedPort) {
      callback('')
    } else {
      callback(selectedPort.portId)
    }
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.session.on('serial-port-added', (event, port) => {
    console.log('serial-port-added FIRED WITH', port);
    for(var i = 0; i < port.length; i++) {
      const info = port[i].getInfo();
      console.log(info);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.session.on('serial-port-removed', (event, port) => {
    console.log('serial-port-removed FIRED WITH', port);
    event.preventDefault();
  })
  
  mainWindow.webContents.session.on('select-serial-port-cancelled', () => {
    console.log('select-serial-port-cancelled FIRED.');
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.session.setPermissionCheckHandler((webContents, permission, requestingOrigin, details) => {
    // This permission check handler is not needed by default but available if you want to limit serial requests
    console.log(`In PermissionCheckHandler`);
    console.log(`Webcontents url: ${webContents.getURL()}`);
    console.log(`Permission: ${permission}`);
    console.log(`Requesting Origin: ${requestingOrigin}`, details);  
    return true;
  });  

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  ipcMain.on('log', (event, msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.

package.json:
{
  "name": "test_bt3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^26.0.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

preload.js:
// All of the Node.js APIs are available in the preload process.
// It has the same sandbox as a Chrome extension.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(selector)
    if (element) element.innerText = text
  }

  for (const type of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
    replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type])
  }
})

const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
    on: (channel, callback) => {
        ipcRenderer.on(channel, callback);
    },
    send: (channel, args) => {
        ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
    },
    
    
    log : (msg) => ipcRenderer.send('log', msg),
      
});

renderer.js:
// This file is required by the index.html file and will
// be executed in the renderer process for that window.
// No Node.js APIs are available in this process because
// `nodeIntegration` is turned off. Use `preload.js` to
// selectively enable features needed in the rendering
// process.

async function testIt() {  

  
  const filters = [
    // Optional filters to limit what serial ports are returned
    // { usbVendorId: 0x2341, usbProductId: 0x0043 },
    // { usbVendorId: 0x2341, usbProductId: 0x0001 }
  ];

  const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort({filters});
  window.electronAPI.log('Selected port');
  window.electronAPI.log(port);

}

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click',testIt);


Are you using nvm?

not that I am aware of @evolutionxbox
